# what should be the control/style used to repeat the same controls

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have some what complex UI requirement, need help in understanding type of control/style/template that can provide this support.Please find the screenshot attached. So, I have some couple of Textbox and Textblocks which gets repeated. How to repeat the controls using WPF?

[image]

---

Hello All, Need some more information about above scenario. Now I am able to accomplish the UI, but I have a list of values for each text box so how to accomplish this binding. For Ex: 
                    
                    and my Itemcontrol is 
So, my ListStpTrade has List of Some values (I am attaching the value how it is holding). So I need  to bind the Textbox of RuleName with the ListSTPTrade's Rulename[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each form represents an instance of the same type in a collection, then you can use an `ItemsControl` with a custom `DataTemplate`.

E.g.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        .. add grid columns/rows here, with TextBox, Label controls etc and Bindings
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect scenario for a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx).

You could bind it to the collection of items, set their ItemsTemplate as needed.  In order to create alternating row colors, you can use AlternationIndex.  See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/28/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-alternating-rows.aspx) for details.

Comment: Really useful. Thanks a ton for ur quick help